# Treat argument of the function as a name of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have small problem. I have script that has many arrays.
My previous function returns a "chosen" variable which is a parameter of my `setBreakValues` function it's also the name of array i want to access values of in my function. Lets say i get "test" return from my other function and pass it into `setBreakValues` i want to access `test[0]` element in test array but it returns the first letter of parameter. I just simply want to use it as a name of array. Is that possible?

Here is the broken code:

```
function setBreakValues(chosen){
    console.log(chosen[0][1])
    $("#totalTime").val($("#firstTime").val())
    var select = document.getElementById('breakValue');
    for(var i = 0; i < chosen.length; i++) {
        var option = document.createElement('option');
        option.innerHTML = chosen[i][0];
        option.value = chosen[i][0];
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    $("#breakValue").change(function(){
        $("#secondPressure").val(chosen[0][1])
    })
}
```

Comment: if you get "test" returned then return[0] is "t" it referres to the first character in the string

Comment: yes but how i can use that "test" to be the name of an array? is that possible?

Comment: If the array is a global, you can use `window[arrayName]` to get the array.

Comment: or you have your arrays as properties of an object you could call them by `object[arrayName]`

Comment: window[arrayName] works but not completly. I've got some dynamic content changed and after few changes it throws me errors with undefined arrays. Is there any other way around window[arrayName] ?

Comment: Any time you find yourself wanting to do this, you should probably be using an object whose keys are the possible arguments.